# Dynamically inject fields on Java objects using ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have this code which I need (it) to inject fields at runtime:

```java
public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    TestEntity entity = (TestEntity) source;
    entity.getPropertyMap().forEach((fieldName, fieldValue) -> {
      // "fieldName" is an arbritary name not known at compile time
      injectFieldTo(source, fieldName, fieldValue);
    });
    entity.setPropertyMap(null);
    super.marshal(source, writer, context);
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Java using *ByteBuddy*? And if not directly (even with just a clone object), what can be done as such fields can be injected into the object? What is the process?

**TestEntity.java**

```java
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {
  private String entityType;
  private String entityId;
  private String dateCreated;
  private String dateUpdated;
  private Boolean publicRead;
  private Boolean publicWrite;
  private Map<String, Object> propertyMap;
}
```

Comment: This is the tutorial page for ByteBuddy: https://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial Quite a read, but it has all the necessary information. Essentially you would have to do new ByteBuddy().rebase().define(new Field(class, name, modifiers, trustedFinal, slot, signature, annotations))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to define a new class to define fields. You can subclass the existing class by `new ByteBuddy().subclass(...)` or use `new ByteBuddy().rebase(...)` to copy the existing class and rename it, in case assignability is not an issue. You define new fields using the `defineField` API.